# 7 years old Rose shrub giving shriveled up leaves and flowers

Tags: leaves, diseases, pruning, growth, roses

I live in South India ,we shifted into our new house 7 years ago and planted this dark pink rose soon after from a nursery .There were 2 of them, but one of them died soon after planting, from shock I think.

But one survived and gave beautiful healthy looking flowers . Now since last 10 months or so ,it seems to stop growing and new leaves are few and small and wrinkled.

[image: flowers]

Buds are also small and shriveled looking with black spots on them. Rose petals are small dry, flower won't bloom fully and die off quicker than usual. I thought because of old age ,but rose plants can live up to at least 20 years in good health it seems.

Winters are not harsh here, and I have tried using cow dung manure and Rose Powder[that's the only rose specific fertilizer you can find here in the market ,having potassium ,Sulphur, magnesium in it].

[image: black bud]

In India, there's not so much extensive knowledge or experience for roses like in UK or other countries. So I don't know what variety of rose this is.

But still, there is no improvement. No other signs of insect infestation or diseases.
[image: under leaf]
What should I do to improve the shrub? Should I prune it?[we already pruned it this April]

Or using cuttings from it to grow new plants?
We tried growing new plants from cutting ,but none actually grow more than a tiny green bud and few leaves. Does applying honey to the cut end help in root formation?

Please help. Links to websites with how-to are appreciated.

*Edit: After Giacomo asked for more clearer photos I observed that there are these black scars like splotches on the leaves.*

Comment: In any case, I would cut a branch and put in a pot. Maybe you overferilized your soil (or you changed too much the pH of soil). Your photos do not help much: out of focus, could you add a photo with top and bottom side of a leave?

Comment: @Giacomo OK,I will add new photos soon